# Magento 1.9.3.1 is not sending any order/shipment emails

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, email, backend

I'm running a website on magento 1.9.3.1 and i'm having email issues. I am not using an SMTP as the installation for the SMTP Pro plugin crashed my website. I am trying to send emails through the default magento email sender.

The strange thing is that when a customer signs up for our website, they receive a welcome/confirmation email automatically, but, when they make an order, an order confirmation/shipping email is not sent. Even when I choose to go to the order it's self and click on 'Send Email' they do not receive anything.

It is for this reason that I am sure my email details are entered correctly, the only problem is how magento handles the order/shipment emails themselves.

These are my settings for the order and shipment emails.
[image: order email]

Comment: Do you have your cron working? If I recall correctly, those emails are being sent by the cron after being pushed to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Magento 1.9.1**, the emails are not being sent **directly** during checkout but instead are being queued. The queue is being processed via your Magento cronjob.

I suggest you to install this free extension [SMTP Pro](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html), set the SMTP config  connexion like Gmail for exemple, and **dont forget** to set `Queue Usage` to `never`, save and your problem is solved.